# Changing date.now in mongoose schema to display date in this format" MMMM Do YYYY"

Tags: javascript, date, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How to I update the date.now in mongoose schema to show only the date in this format "MMMM Do YYYY"
the mongoose schema

```
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
},
```

the format i get in the database

```
date: 2021-09-21T13:02:49.856+00:00
```

how to i remove the T13:02:49.856+00:00 and change the format to "MMMM Do YYYY"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could extract the date first, using `date.slice(0,10)` on your `date: 2021-09-21T13:02:49.856+00:00`.Then you may want to convert it using a handy time-dealing library, like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/).

Comment: A consequence of this approach is that it may change the date. Far better to parse the entire string then format the date from there. This question has been asked [many, many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date).